# Syntax Error The source line is 1

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, unix, grep

I have a server list in hostlist file and I am trying to execute below script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for server in `cat hostlist`; do
ssh $server 'hostname ;id $(cat /etc/passwd | grep Luyang | awk -F '[:]' '{print $1}') ; id  ppandey' >> b
done
```

I want to fetch outputs for id command of user Luyang . For the same I have mentioned `id $(cat /etc/passwd | grep Luyang | awk -F '[:]' '{print $1}')` but I am getting errors while running the script .

I also tried to put '\' infront of all special characters but no luck.

Comment: What actual error(s) are you getting?

Comment: Try putting " instead of ' in front of hostname and at the end. Because you use other ones inside it closes it....

Answer (score 1):

You should check in the shell's manual how escaping/quoting works.
And look into the features of awk as well, just for simplicity which usually leads to readability in addition to speed.

This may help:

```
ssh yourhost "hostname ;id \$( awk -F: '/Luyang/ {print \$1}' /etc/passwd)"
```